# Update row using If-Else condition using inner join in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update, inner-join

```
if (quantity - @TransferQnty) = 0
   update PD 
   set attrited = 'true'
else 
  update PD 
  set quantity = quantity - @TransferQnty

from K_RT_PurchaseDet as PD
inner join K_RT_Productdetails as PS on PD.product=PS.sno where PS.productname=@Purchaseid
```

I want to update `attrited=true` when `quantity=0` else I want to update quantity column. I tried like this but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need
`from K_RT_PurchaseDet as PD
inner join K_RT_Productdetails as PS on PD.product=PS.sno where PS.productname=@Purchaseid` anyway?

Comment: I am passing one parameter as string but actually K_RT_PurchaseDet this table have that column as int that's why i wrote joins

Answer (score 0):

try below,

```
UPDATE PD SET 
ATTRITED=(CASE WHEN (QUANTITY-@TRANSFERQNTY = 0)
                THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE ATTRITED END),
QUANTITY = (CASE WHEN (QUANTITY-@TRANSFERQNTY != 0)
                 THEN QUANTITY-@TRANSFERQNTY
             ELSE QUANTITY END)

FROM K_RT_PURCHASEDET AS PD
INNER JOIN K_RT_PRODUCTDETAILS AS PS ON PD.PRODUCT=PS.SNO WHERE PS.PRODUCTNAME=@PURCHASEID
```

Comment: YOU are correct but quantity-@transferqnty!=0 at that i want to update quantity column quantity=quantity-@transferqnty how can I?